# How can I modify this code to have the bot read a full discord message for phrase and tag specific roles in response?

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I am trying to make a bot for discord that responses when it sees the phrase 'Tier 5 Egg' in any part of a message.

```
bot.on("message", message => {
  if(message.content === 'Tier 5 Egg') {
    message.channel.send('A Tier 5 Egg has appear in @role1 @role2');
  }
});
```

When it responses I want it to send a message and also tag two specific roles in its response. I have tried doing the @ and including its role ID and it just puts it in plain text. I also can't figure out how to change this so it reads the entire message for that specific phrase.

Comment: `message.content.indexOf('Tier 5 Egg') > -1` should do the trick for you. For the roles you'll have to do something like this: `let role = message.channel.server.roles.get('roleName')` which will return an Role object, after that you can just concatenate the role object on the string massage and it will mention automatically like this: `message.channel.send('A Tier 5 Egg has appear in ' + role);`

Comment: The first part works beautifully...I'm not sure where would I be inserting the

let role = message.channel.server.roles.get('roleName')

Comment: Don't forget to mark the answer as correct. :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see here on the [Documentation](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Role?scrollTo=toString) once you get the role you just need to concatenate it with the message string and it'll automatically mention the role so you could try something like this:

```
bot.on("message", message => {
  if(message.content.indexOf('Tier 5 Egg') > -1) {
    let role1 = message.channel.guild.roles.find('name', 'role1Name');
    let role2 = message.channel.guild.roles.find('name', 'role1Name');
    message.channel.send(`A Tier 5 Egg has appear in ${role1} ${role2}`);
  }
});
```

Comment: It seems to have worked! I had to add the > -1 back in because it kept re-reading past messages and continued to tag those roles.....thanks so much for your help!

Comment: lol! Yeah, you are right. I forgot about the `> -1` my bad. I'm glad I could help. The way it is now, it will only work if people type `Tier 5 Egg` exactly, in other words, it is case sensitive. If you'd like to accept `tier 5 egg`, `TiEr 5 eGg` and so on, you should do `message.content.toLowerCase().indexOf('tier 5 egg')`.